# Class documentation not showing up in Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, markup

I'm writing a UIKit library which need a lot of documentation.

I've added the documentation as regular in every library but it's not showing up within the quick help.

Example:

```
import UIKit

/// An extension of Apples [`UILabel`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uilabel).
///
/// The whole label is configurable within the storyboard builder using the`@IBInspectable`.
///
///     let myLabel = MyLabel()
///
@IBDesignable
open class MyLabel: UILabel {
}
```

All I get here is: [image]

If reorder the documentation to:

```
/// An extension of Apples [`UILabel`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uilabel).
///
/// The whole label is configurable within the storyboard builder using the`@IBInspectable`.
///
///     let myLabel = MyLabel()
///

import UIKit

@IBDesignable
open class MyLabel: UILabel {
}
```

Or

import UIKit

```
@IBDesignable
/// An extension of Apples [`UILabel`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uilabel).
///
/// The whole label is configurable within the storyboard builder using the`@IBInspectable`.
///
///     let myLabel = MyLabel()
///
open class MyLabel: UILabel {
}
```

I at least I see: 
[image]

But nothing of my written documentation. Method or field documentation seem to work properly.

How to I correctly write class documentation? Has this something todo with ?`@IBDesignables` other classes seem to work fine?

I've tried it in Xcode 9.x.x and Xcode 10.0 beta.

<sub>Jazzy does export everything properly.</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the Grave accents (`) in the first line of your comment. Xcode doesn't seem to support that within links! If you remove them, your quick help will be rendered.

Instead of

```
/// An extension of Apples [`UILabel`](https://...)
```

use

```
/// An extension of Apples [UILabel](https://...)
```

Comment: You are the man! It only doesn't render if the ` are within the link. Please edit your answer with an example which works and which not so it's more clear. Thank you very much!

Comment: Like it that way?